# Don't autofocus the Close > Duplicate search box on mobile web

Tags: bug, mobile-web

I am using the mobile web version of Stack Overflow. I opened a question with one close vote and a "Possible duplicate of..." comment. I clicked close as to vote in agreement, but once I tapped the duplicate link, the search box was autofocused, causing the keyboard to appear. Please don't autofocus the search box.